# ArcGIS geoprocessing DomainToTable_Management script crashing

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing, domains

I needed to dump all of the domains in my file geodatabase so missing values can be identified. The script runs fine if the domain name has no spaces but, unfortunately this one has many multi-word domain names. Renaming the domains isn't practical and ModelBuilder is not an option. I can list (ListDomains) all of the domains, regardless of the name and loop through everyone of them. The  Toolbox version successfully but there are too many domains for that. Here is the script.

```
import arcpy

domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(pathname)

fileout = open('filename', 'w')

for domain in domains:

    name = domain.name

    print(name)

    txtline = name,'\n'

    fileout.writelines(txtline)

    arcpy.DomainToTable_management(inTable,name,outTable + name,"Code","Description")

fileout.close()
```

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.6, Pro 2.3

Comment: 2,4 is newest, if you can't update and try that I'd suggest sending this directly to Tech Support. It obviously shouldn't crash, so it sounds like it might be a bug.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make use of [Validate Table Name](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/validatetablename.htm) and GISPro's [Alter Domain](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/alter-domain.htm). You can alter your domain names using `Validate Table Name` to remove spaces.

Untested since I don't have ArcGIS Pro:

```
inGdb = r"Domained\gdb"
outGdb = r"output\gdb"

#----
print ("importing")
import arcpy
import os

print ("listing domains")
domains = [d.name for d in arcpy.da.ListDomains (inGdb)]
for dom in domains:
    print (dom)
    #get valid table name
    altDom = arcpy.ValidateTableName (dom, outGdb)
    print (altDom)
    if altDom != dom:
        #alter domain to valid name
        arcpy.AlterDomain_management (inGdb, dom, altDom)
    outTab = os.path.join (outGdb, altDom)
    arcpy.DomainToTable_management (inGdb, altDom, outTab, "Code", "Description")
    if altDom != dom:
        #alter name back to original
        arcpy.AlterDomain_management (inGdb, altDom, dom)
```